# Mysql query for updating next row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display a news-tip daily and my table structure as below.

```
| id  |  ndate      |News Tip |
+------+----------------------+
| 1541 | NULL       | news1   |
| 1545 | 14-10-2010 | news2   | 
| 1567 | NULL       | news3   |
| 1568 | NULL       | news4   |
| 1582 | NULL       | news5   |
     ....     ....      
| 1702 | NULL       | news217 |
```

and the query `select * from newstip where ndate!=NULL` and checks whether ndate matches current date its ok. if not i need to update next row (1567 in this case) to current date and all others to NULL.

id is unique but **not in sequence** so below query not possible.

```
update newstip set ndate='15-10-2010' where id=(id+1); //failure
```

How to solve this situation ?. i'm using php to this process;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE newstip
SET ndate = '15-10-2010'
WHERE id = ( SELECT id FROM newstip WHERE id > 1545 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 )
```

This won't update anything if no record has an `id > 1545`.

Answer (score 3):

If your `id` is going to be bigger, you could just query for the next row and update it. In your case:

```
UPDATE newstip SET ndate = '15-10-2010' WHERE id > 1545 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

I should mention that this statement is not replication safe.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the `id` of the last complete row is stored in `:old_id`:

```
UPDATE `newstip` SET `ndate`=15-10-2010` WHERE `id` > :old_id ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hole procedure in mysql to update all the rows below

CREATE PROCEDURE upDates()

BEGIN

DECLARE dat=date('16-10-2010');

DECLARE idd INT;

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id fron newstrip where id>1545 order by id;

read_loop: LOOP

```
FETCH cur1 INTO a;

IF done THEN

  LEAVE read_loop;

END IF;

update newstrip set ndate=dat where id=a;

dat=DATE_ADD(dat,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

END LOOP;